# All clustering possibilities for a graph

Tags: algorithms, graph

Is there a *known* algorithm for finding all clustering possibilities for a directed graph?

**EDIT:**

By *cluster* i mean a *weakly* connected sub-graph G, so that E(G) > 0.

By a *clustering possibility* I mean a set of non-overlapping clusters so that no other cluster can be added to the set without breaking this condition.

Ie.:

Given

[image]

All possible clusters are:

[image]

All clustering possibilities are:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to give us the formal definition of what a cluster might be? From your examples I cannot deduce it.

Comment: It looks to me that, from your example, by "cluster" you might mean "connected sub-graph" in the un-directed sense (maybe). In which case you can probably consult this stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-subgraphs